# How to configure Appium-Flutter-Driver in windows? Which IDE is preferable?

Tags: java, appium, flutter-test

I'am new to Automation testing. I have to **perform automation testing on Flutter app**. I came across appium-flutter-driver through this link: [https://github.com/truongsinh/appium-flutter-driver][1].

Unable to configure the driver in my project. Currently using, **IDE:Eclipse 2018-12, Build:Maven build using TestNg Java.** I have installed the Appium-flutter-driver in my system using the given command **"npm i -g Appium-flutter-driver"** in GitHub. But unable to configure driver into my project. There is no ".jar" file.

**Need Help:**

1. How to configure the Appium-flutter-driver into project?
2. Which IDE is preferable to configure the driver and perform automation testing?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to install flutter driver, use command npm I appium-flutter-driver, which creates node modules directory in your project directory with flutter library. Later you need to import library in your file/class.

Hope this helps..Happy coding

Comment: I did in the way you suggested but still didn't solve my issue. Thanks for your response.